# IIS 8.5 Request Management | Queue | Timeout problem

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, worker-process, web-garden

I have a WCF SOAP service that receives too many synchronous requests from other systems

I am having problem when too many request comes at that time IIS Queue will not provide proper result and server memory and CPU usage is gone high and discard request or time out

I did a normal Load test (100 requests with 100 concurrent user) and the IIS started to discard the requests after the maximum queue length reach as well as all  the request coming delays to provide the response and Other requests coming in are delayed until the first one either times out, or responds.

Below is server configuration

[image]
WCF application code is tested with Resharper tool and there is no object or memory dispose issue

Is there any settings for setup application pool or worker process to manage queue ?

Can i apply web garden in Application ?

Please help me to solve this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "WCF application code is tested with Resharper tool and there is no object or memory dispose issue". That's the worst claim, as ReSharper only reports the obvious issues it can detect. Please use a performance/memory profiler to do some serious digging and learn where the bottlenecks are. You either resolve them so as to handle more load, or accept them as any system has a limitation.

Comment: Lex Li has a point. I prefer PerfMon. I watch the graphs for Memory, IIS Queue length, and CPU (maybe a few others too). If those are not saturated, you can change settings in IIS to allow a larger queue.  However, if your server is saturated, don't increase the size of the queue because that will only make things worse. Instead, consider "scaling-out" (adding another load-balanced server).

Comment: @tgolisch:Thank you for information. will execute Perfmon tool and before week ago i have executed as well but not found satisfied result. Also i am doing RND to understand all the option of PerfMon.

Comment: @tgolisch: Can you please help me to change settings in IIS to allow a larger Queue. Can i increase worker process ?.If yes then how many worker process i can set? As off now only one worker process.

Comment: The queue length is configured in the application pool for your IIS app. Right click, "Advanced Settings..." (General) section.

Comment: @tgolisch: Thanks for the answer and as help of google i just found one things like i want to increase worker process (web garden) but i don't know how many worker process is suitable for WCF service